# Расширение chrome, парсинг

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, парсер

Необходимо написать простейшее расширение для парсинга сайта, а конкретней - каждые 5 минут получать статус сайта. Он находится в

```
<span class="current_status">Онлайн</span>
```

на странице site.com.

При нажатии на кнопку расширения, popup.js работает на ура.

Не получается написать фоновый скрипт.js , для парсинга через заданное время.
Вот работающий код popup.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://site.com", true);
xhr.send(null);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) 
    {
        if (xhr.responseText) 
        {
            var data = xhr.responseText;

            var status = $('.current_status',data).html();

            chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
            path : "images/icon2.png"
            });

            $('#wrapper').html(status);
        }
    }
}
});
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что написать в фоновой eventPage.js. Именно процесс получения данных интересует. с setInterval я разобрался вроде.
Вот неработающий скрипт eventPage:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://site.com", true);
xhr.send(null);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) 
    {
        if (xhr.responseText) 
        {
            var data = xhr.responseText;

            status = getElementsByClassName('current_text')[0];

            alert(status);


        }
    }
};
```

Comment: что именно не работает?

Comment: @Grundy ошибка: Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementsByClassName is not defined

Comment: метод _getElementsByClassName_ находится в объекте _document_, поэтому вызывать его следует так `document.getElementsByClassName(...)`. Но не могу сказать доступен ли этот объект в _eventPage.js_. Кроме того, вы получили текст который записали в _data_ - это обычная строка, сначала вам построить DOM из него, как это делает jQuery в вашем примере выше

Comment: @Grundy Вы можете подсказать как это сделать? с document.getElementsByClassName скрипт выполняется без ошибок в консоли. но В алерте выдаёт Underfined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первое, [*getElementsByClassName*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) - это не глобальная функция, поэтому при таком вызове вы получаете ошибку.

Второе, для разбора html и построения DOM можно воспользоваться браузером, например, создать элемент, установить ему внутренний html, и далее внутри уже искать нужный элемент

```
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML = data;

var status = element.getElementsByClassName('current_text')[0];
```

В переменной статус хранится сам элемент. Чтобы получить текст, нужно воспользоваться одним из свойств: [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText), [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

```
console.log(status.innerHTML);
console.log(status.innerText);
console.log(status.textContent);
```

Comment: Спасибо, я понял логику. Но, похоже, что в коде ещё не всё на своих местах. alert(status) выдаёт : [object HTMLSpanElement]

Comment: попробуйте status.innerText или status.innerHTML

Comment: @Алексе, потому что _status_ это не текст, а именно html элемент, вы можете например вы вести его в лог и посмотреть какие свойства у него есть, а так же воспользоваться предложенными _@Darth_ либо _textContent_

Comment: @Алексе, обновил ответ

Comment: Большое Спасибо всем! Работают все предложенные вами методы.